# mongo atlas or aws - Internal or External connection

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2, server, amazon-rds, mlab

i am working on my next project currently which works 100% on mongo,
my past projects worked on SQL + Mongo on which i used AWS RDS + AWS EC2 and could connect them both in AWS internal IP which result me with much faster connection.

Now in mongo there is alot of fancy cloud servers like MLab and MongoDB Atlas which is actually cheaper then AWS.

My concern is that moving back to external DB connection will be slower and more network consuming then the internal connection in RDS

Have anyone experienced in such issue? maybe the different isn't that big as i make it but i need it to be optimized

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your setup. Many of the "fancy" services also host stuff on AWS, so latency is minimal. Some even offer "private environments" or such, so you can hide your databases from public view.

The only thing left to care about is the *amount* of network traffic. But this will be your problem regardless of your database host. You can test this relatively easily (e.g. get a trial from one of the providers and test for throughput, or raise your own MongoDB docker cluster to use as a test etc) just to get an idea of the performance range you'll be in.